# TPT mapping Entity Framework CTP4 behaving like TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, code-first

I am writing my code as suggested,

```
public class A 
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string Astring {get;set;}
}

public class B : A
{
    public string Bstring {get;set;}
}

builder.Entity<A>().MapHierarchy( u=> new { ... }).ToTable("A");
builder.Entity<B>().MapHierarchy( u=> new { ... }).ToTable("B");
```

... = I have all the properties mentiond and u.Id in both.

I also have `DbSet<A> A {get;set;}` and `DbSet<B> B {get;set;}`
and `ObjectSet` properties for both when I use Model builder

```
builder.Entity<A>
builder.Entity<B>
```

This results in Table A being created with a discriminator column and Id, Astring, Bstring.  This is the default TPH mapping, not sure why this is happening.
Thanks

Comment: I think the title of this question was correct and should have not be changed from TPT to TPH since as the Questioner mentioned, he is looking for TPT behavior but getting TPH from EF.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.cincura.net/231783-ultimate-efv4-ctp4-code-first-full-mapping-example-using-firebird/

The Author, Translator part in the example above has the correct TPT solution,
 for some reason the example on

http://romiller.com/2010/09/29/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-code-first-inheritance-mapping/

dosn't work for me